# What to do when looking for clarification on already posted solution?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for a solution and found the following:

[Joomla! 3 : list articles from multiple categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771939/joomla-3-list-articles-from-multiple-categories)

In my case this isn't doing what it is supposed to and I want to ask the user providing the solution what I am doing wrong by posting a comment. But I can't as I do not have enough reputation. On the other hand I guess I'm not supposed to ask the same question in a new topic, refering back to an already posted answer?

What am I supposed to do in this case?